# Why is SKSpriteNode(fileNamed:) generating nil in iOS using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

Why is init(fileNamed:) of SKSpriteNode generating a nil?

I've tried the following code. I show only the code that is related to the problem:

```
let road = SKSpriteNode(fileNamed: "road.png")

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    print("road", road as Any) // road nil
    if let road = self.road {
        road.position = view.center
        road.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: road.size)
        print(road.physicsBody?.isDynamic as Any, "!")
        road.physicsBody?.pinned = true
        addChild(road)
    }

}
```

I get a nil regardless of whether the image file is a regular png or an animated png file.

Comment: Has `"road.png"` been added to your project?   In the *File Inspector*, make sure the *Target Membership* for your app is checked.

Comment: @vacawama Yes to both questions.

Comment: dont use ".png"

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I've tried that. I get the same result.

Comment: Then road is not an asset

Comment: @Knight0fDragon "road" is not an asset. It's a file I dragged and dropped into my Xcode project. If I was using an asset, I would have used SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "road"). It's a large image intended to span the entire height of the display (when in portrait orientation). Because it's so large, I decided to put it in the project as a file instead of an asset.

Comment: 1, that is just silly, and 2, that means you need to tell spritekit where the file is at in your bundle.  Just put it as an asset, it makes no difference based on size

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Yes. I might have to do that. Thanks. However, I don't think I have to tell SKSpriteNode the path, because with SKAudioNode, I can just use the name of the file without its extension, and I don't have to supply a path.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:)` instead of `SKSpriteNode(fileNamed:)`.

`SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:)` - loads image as texture for you and creates a node.

`SKSpriteNode(fileNamed:)` is actually init method from SKNode, as it says in official doc:

> init?(fileNamed: String)
> Creates a new node by loading an archive file from the game’s main bundle.

So there are two different methods (constructors), from two different classes, and even though one inherit from another they should not be confused.